# How to use servoKit library and GPIO pins

Tags: python, gpio, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano, adafruit-circuitpython

I have been struggling because of the library [adafruit_servokit](https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/projects/servokit/en/latest/api.html#module-adafruit_servokit) has been stopping me from assigning pins. When I try to do this:

```
from adafruit_servokit import ServoKit # Servo library that works with Jetson
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO                # Part of PWM DC motor control 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)               # Error here
```

It returns an error saying this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "brew.py", line 4, in <module>
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Jetson/GPIO/gpio.py", line 317, in setmode
    raise ValueError("A different mode has already been set!")
ValueError: A different mode has already been set!
```

I just need a way to control my servos and use my GPIO pins at the same time.

I'm open to buying new parts as well.

Comment: According to this response https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12966/what-is-the-difference-between-board-and-bcm-for-gpio-pin-numbering the setmode only chnange how you need to set the numbers of the port to use. Given that looks like ServoKit already set the mode to BCM mode, could you use that mode in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to use digitalio: https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-on-raspberrypi-linux/digital-i-o